# JavaScript Array problem solving question

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could you please help me to solve the below problem.

If counter is 2 then the function should return `[ [1,2], [1,3] , [1,4], [1,5], [2,3], [2,4], [2,5], [3,4], [3,5], [4,5] ]`

If counter is 3 then the function should return `[ [1,2,3], [1,2,4] , [1,2,5], [1,3,4], [1,3,5], [1,4,5], [2,3,4], [2,3,5], [2,4,5], [3,4,5] ]`

If counter is 4 then the function should return `[ [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,5] , [1,2,4,5], [1,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5] ]`

```
var inputArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
function getPairs(arr, start, end, counter, result) {
    if(end < arr.length) {
        result.push([arr[start], arr[end]]);
        return getPairs(arr, start, end + 1, counter, result);
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
function iterateArr(arr, start, end, counter, result) {
    if(result == null) result = [];
    if(start === end) {
        result = getPairs(arr, start, start + 1, counter, result);
        if(result[0].length === counter) {
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return getNextPairs(arr, result, counter);
        }
    }
    else {
        if(start == 3) {
            return result;
        } 
        result = getPairs(arr, start, start + 1, counter, result);
        return iterateArr(arr, start + 1, end, counter, result);
    }
}
var counter = 2;
var result = iterateArr(inputArr, 0, inputArr.length - counter, counter);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: "Help" implies you would do at least some of the work.

Comment: It works for counter 2. But counter 3 and above it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but it isn't a code-writing service. Please try to do it on your own, and we can *help* get it working. But please don't ask questions like "*I want this, please do that!*". Read these pages: [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask), and [How do I create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and hand over the rest of the array and a reduced counter.

```js
function getPairs(array, counter) {
    var result = [];
    if (!counter) return [[]];
    array.forEach((v, i, a) => 
        getPairs(a.slice(i + 1), counter - 1)
            .forEach(a => result.push([v, ...a]))
    );
    return result;
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(getPairs(array, 1).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 2).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 3).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 4).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) version

```js
function getPairs(array, counter) {
    if (!counter) return [[]];
    return array.flatMap((v, i, a) => 
        getPairs(a.slice(i + 1), counter - 1).map(a => [v, ...a])
    );
}

const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(getPairs(array, 1).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 2).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 3).map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(getPairs(array, 4).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina Scholz. I had only concentrated on appending one flow from start to end.You achieved the expected output from appending values from end to start. I have learned a lot from your solution.